# How to view the literal content of a ZSH string containing colour codes

Tags: zsh

I'm assuming it's some sort of flag to `typeset` but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Like it or not, the color codes *are* part of the literal content of the string. Any color code you specify is just a set of bytes intended to be interpreted by a particular *consumer* of that string (usually, a terminal that will display the string).

Comment: I recommend distinguishing between the "pure" version of a string and its "display" version. E.g., `label="foo"; displayLabel="%F{green}$label%f"`.

Comment: It's for debugging someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have valid ANSI color codes and want to get rid of them, this regex will do the trick: `\x1b\[[0-?]*[ -/]*m`.

With `set -o extendedglob`:

```
print -r "${variable//$'\e'\[[0-?]#[ -\/]#m/}"
```

Perl oneliner:

```
perl -pe 's/\x1b\[[0-?]*[ -\/]*m//g'
```